# Better way to control flow around database query

Tags: python, loops, peewee

In my program I need to read a very large table (it exceeds memory storage) and have myself writing the following construct to read from the table and do some work.  While I know it's very possible to re-write the select into an iterator style it still has the basic structure that is follows:

```
    found = True
    start = 0
    batch = 2500
    while found:
        found = False
        for obj in Channel.select().limit(batch).offset(start):
            found = True

            # do some big work...

        start += batch
```

What I would like to do is have something that don't carry around as many klunky state variables.  Ideas of how to clean up this bit of mess?

FYI - I've tried this as well, not sure I like it any better:

```
@staticmethod
def qiter(q, start=0, batch=25000):
    obj = True
    while obj:
        for obj in q.limit(batch).offset(start):
            yield obj
        start += batch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest thing I found is the following:

```
for start in itertools.count(0, 2500):
    objs = Channel.select().limit(2500).offset(start)
    if not objs:
        break
    for obj in objs:
        # do some big work...
```

Basically it's a combination of two things:

- the `count` iterator (from the itertools package of the standard library) reduces the batch counting to a minimum, and
- using a separate test and the `break` statement to get out of it.

In detail:

The `count` iterator is pretty simple: it yield the infinite series 0, 2500, 5000, 7500, ... . As this loop would never end, we need to `break` out of it somewhere. This is where the if-statement comes into play. If `objs` is an empty list, the `break` exists the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just iterating and don't want to use up all your RAM you might check out the "iterator()" method on QueryResultWrapper.

For instance, say you need to iterate over 1,000,000 rows of data and serialize it:

```
# let's assume we've got 1M stat objects to dump to csv
stats_qr = Stat.select().execute()

# our imaginary serializer class
serializer = CSVSerializer()

# loop over all the stats and serialize
for stat in stats_qr.iterator():
    serializer.serialize_object(stat)
```

Below is a link to the documentation:

http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html#iterating-over-lots-of-rows